# Cannot read property 'MyProperty' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angular

In my Angular2 template, I have the following binding:

```
{{Stringify(result)}}
{{result.MyProperty}}
```

`Stringify` is a function that returns `JSON.stringify` of the input object. The `Stringify` function returned a JSON string that shows the name and value of `MyProperty`.

However, the second line returns a

> TypeError. Cannot read property 'MyProperty' of undefined in {{result.MyProperty}}.

`JSON.stringify` clearly shows that this property / field exists, so why am I getting an error?

Comment: I don't think result is assigned the result of Stringify

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's there it can be accessed and JS wouldn't throw

Try instead

```
{{result?.MyProperty}}
```

maybe Angular makes an attempt to access `result.MyProperty` before `result` has a value while `Stringify(result)` doesn't choke on `null`. 
When `result` is updated in the meantime (maybe because the value was received from the server, the view would update before you can recognized that an empty string was shown before.
Your question doesn't provide enough context to know.

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/791
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#expression-operators (from a comment below - thanks to @MarkRajcok )

Comment: You're right. result is populated from a web service call within a subscribe. It broke before it had a chance to render, and so adding "?" fixed it.

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer, please can u share a reference for this your solution? It's new to me, and I'd like to know more. Thanks

Comment: @kennasoft https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/791. The expression after `?.` is not evaluated if the expression before is `null` or `undefined` and `null` is returned instead.

Comment: Thanks. That's a very handy feature.

Comment: @kennasoft, the github link Günter provided is a good read.  If you wanted a Angular.io doc link, the Elvis operator is discussed in the Template Syntax doc, section [Template expression operators](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#expression-operators).